# Delphi $E directive

Tags: delphi, file-extension, compiler-directives

I am trying to automatically generate the extension of my DLLs to get *FileName.$(Platform).DLL*. Supposedly I can use **{$E ext}** to set the extension to FileName.ext, and I want *FileName.ext.dll*

The problem is if I use `{$E ext}` I get `FileName.ext` as expected, but when I use `{$E ext.dll}` I get `FileName.ext.ext.dll`. My compiler directives in the *.dpr file reads:

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
    {$E x64.dll}
  {$ELSE}
    {$E x86.dll}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

This creates `FileName.x64.x64.dll` or `FileName.x86.x86.dll`. Am I missing something? Is there a way to avoid the double "ext" on XE7?

Comment: I don't think it's designed to work that way. Could you do the name change in an AfterBuild handler instead?

Comment: I am not familiar with AfterBuild handlers. I will lookup and read (any pointers would be appreciated)

Comment: Project->Options->Build Events.

Comment: I could get "Win32" instead of "x86" if the following works: But it exits with Error Code 1 in PostBuild:  *ren $(OutputDir)$(OutputFileName) $(OutputDir)$(OutputName).$(Platform)$(OutputExt)*

Comment: The directive is for setting the extension but you are trying to modify the filename. Do that with a post build event or similar.

Comment: Just use `$LIBSUFFIX`, You should not try and control the file extension in the source

Comment: $LIBSUFFIX seems to work only with *.bpl not *.dll.